# is socket thread safe in writing or reading a 1byte?

Tags: python, sockets, thread-safety

as i have found on thread safety of socket, it was not,

But how about each thread accesses a socket to write or read only one byte at a once.(1 byte means 1 character)

is it also un-safe?

i am coding in python.

Comment: I fail to see a case where writing to the same socket from different threads (even synchronized, even one byte at a time) would result in usable and not interleaved data. Could you provide a use case?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - you could have an event source that encodes its information in a single char (e.g., a switch on/off event). I have no idea what the use case is here, but there are some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket API is thread safe (at least on linux and windows) to the extent that the system won't crash and the data will all be transferred. Its just that data sent among threads may be interleaved and there is no guarantee what any given thread will receive. But the minumum unit of transfer is 1 byte so if you have a protocol where messages are only 1 byte and interleaving doesn't make a difference, ... send away!